# Quiero usar la librería DataTable para mostrar un arreglo que ya tengo hecho pero no se como mostrar uno ya hecho

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, datatables, knockoutjs

estoy programando en visual studio con net core 6, estoy haciendo una pagina web, quiero mostrar mis resultados de una consulta que ya tenia hecho la hago con knockoutjs y la guardo en un arreglo y luego la muestro en pantalla pero lo quiero hacer con DataTable pero al parecer es complicado usar las dos al mismo tiempo entones ya que knockout me guarda la información en un arreglo quería usar eso para llenar la datatable pero no se como hacerlo.
Lo que quiero saber al final es como llenar un DataTable con un arreglo que ya tengo hecho.

[image: Este seria mi js lo que tiene la variable response ahorita lo pongo]

[image: Esto tiene la variable response]

[image: Este error me sale]

[image: Este es mi html]

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: Modifique viendo el link pero igual no me sale

Comment: Ese ejemplo era para un array de arrays, pero en tu caso es un array de objetos. De momento prueba cambiando los `title` por `data`, y en lugar de poner los títulos, pon las propiedades (id, name, lastname...) a ver si con eso te sale algo al menos

Comment: Ya sirvió con eso, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro :)  (porque no tengo ni idea de asp, visual-studio ni knockoutjs y dudaba si tenian o no relevancia en la solución, je)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.